# How to programatically disable top/bottom handy toggles?

Tags: ios, ios7

iOS 7 introduced the top/bottom handy toggles to allow you quickly access some control center features. However my application uses the full screen for touching and users can accidentally slide the toggles. I know the user can disable it from the control center but how I can turn that off in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable Control Center in iOS 7 programmatically and if not, what are alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the moment it is not possible to disable control center programmatically. See also: [Is it possible to disable Control Center in iOS 7 programmatically and if not, what are alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w)

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the status bar using this delegate in IOS7:

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

And this method in IOS6.1 and prior:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

This will prevent the accidental launch of the handy toggles. Try it.

Comment: @downvoter: Please specify a reason for the downvote.