# How to hide iOS bottom control center?

Tags: ios, controls, statusbar

I am using swipe gesture from bottom to top in my app, but when I do this, Apple control center comes up. Can I prevent bottom control center from coming up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not disable it. You can find more explanation here:

[Link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding your status bar will make the behaviour of your app slightly different, but as far as I know there is no public API to prevent the control or notification center to appear on screen.

You can disable the status bar in IOS7 like this:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

And for IOS6 and prior:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Comment: thank you but I use this code already.
if I use this code, ios top status bar is disappear.