# Preventing the drop-down menus from accidentally appearing when swiping on device

Tags: iphone, ios8, swipe

Ok i have this painting app, so obviously the user is sliding their finger all over the screen.The problem is, the drop-down and pull-up menus on the iPhone are opening up when painting at the top or bottom of the screen. You would think apple would have figured these are going to get accidentally swiped, but is there a solution? I highly doubt your able to disable these just for your app because they are primary functions of the device. But i also have heard that Apple has allowed a lot more freedom to developers with recent update. so maybe these menus can be prevented from being opened within my app? If not please share your ideas to solve this problem, they are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it but you can make it so that arrows appear so that the user has to pull twice to make the control center or notification center appear. See this answer and question on SO for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926336/1502490

Also, if turning off the status bar is not an option (or you're already doing that) you should think about decreasing your drawing canvas to prevent accidental drags on the notification or control centers.