# Programmatically show Control Center ios

Tags: ios, control-center

Is there any API to show(swipe-up) the control center programmatically in app?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable Control Center in iOS 7 programmatically and if not, what are alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w)

Comment: @RemingHsu I don't want to disable the control-center, i want to show it programmatically.

Comment: Are you trying to rickroll us all?

Comment: @Cyrille No, i am not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about non jailbroken devices: **NO.**