# Tab Bar item detects only longer click

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, tabbar

I am using custom tab bar without controller.
[image]
 Here is the code I use to detect when item is selected.

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch(item.tag) {
    case 1:
        // do something
    case 2:
        // do something
    case 3:
        // do something
    default:
        return

    }
}
```

My problem is that I have to press a bit longer to select an item. It does not recognize simple click like button click. Anyone know how to solve it.

Thank you for any suggestion or idea.

Comment: Stanislav creator of guildwork? is the tabbar in some kind of scrollview / tableview / collectionview ?

Comment: Is tabbar located at the bottom of the screen? Control center gesture recognizer is located in area that 20 points from bottom. It can delay touches on tabbar.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Nope, not the creator :) Yes, i have a scrollview, but it is not inside it. Over it.

Comment: @Kirsteins yes, it is at the bottom of th screen

Comment: I think you are affected by problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w. To be sure you can try to put tabbar 20 points away from bottom and see if it works correctly.

Comment: @Kirsteins tried, did not help. Also tried to uninstall ScrollView, move it up and deselect "delaysContentTouches" ... still does not work instantly, have to click and hold a bit. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in UIScrollView or UITableView. If your tab bar is within any of these controls deselect property "delaysContentTouches" in interface builder

Comment: deselecting property "delaysContentTouches" did not help. ehh