# Stop control center activating by accident in iOS 11

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios11

I have a Spritekit game that was working well in iOS 10 but is now completely unplayable. The game is based around manipulating SKNodes on the bottom left and right of the screen in landscape view.

Now with iOS 11 the control centre swipes up from the bottom of the screen as I try to play.
It feels like Apple have increased the ease with which the centre comes up, probably for the iPhone X.

Is there any way to stop this or reduce the sensitivity?

The only similar question has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926336/943544) but I've already got statusBarHidden set to true.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}
```

I'm overriding touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded on the SKNodes and I don't think I can use any of the gesture recognizers to manipulate the nodes, the timings weren't suitable for my needs.

I can't ask players to disable the control centre gesture with a popup, I don't think anyone would do that.

Answer (score 13):

I've found overriding `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` on my main viewcontroller will stop the control centre coming up. It does however show an up arrow which is quite intrusive and may obscure the game view. I haven't yet found a way to hide the arrow.

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return .bottom
}
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys)

Comment: Things would change with iOS 11 and iPhone X, control center is to swipe down from the top of the screen

Comment: If anyone works out if it's possible to also hide the arrow let us know :)