# NSNotificationCenter in swift 4.0? What needs to be set for a arrow label to appear when dragging down?

Tags: swift4

NSNotificationCenter in swift 4.0? What needs to be set for a label to appear when dragging?

As shown in the picture two?

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: The solution -> Swift 4+ code:

    class GameViewController: UIViewController { }
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
        return .all
    }

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306449/is-it-possible-to-disable-control-center-in-ios-7-programmatically-and-if-not-w/46910913#46910913

Answer (score 0):

For adding custom content UI to your notifications (both local and remote), you need to use **Notification Content Extension**.

With Notification Content Extension, you can add whatever custom interface you want to add to the notifications.

The custom UI appears on expanding the notification in the notification center.

This feature is available from **iOS-10**

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ios-10-notifications-inshorts-all-in-one-ad727e03983a - Detailed discussion on notifications content extension and other concepts.

https://github.com/pgpt10/RichNotificationSample - A full-fledged example for implementing Notification content extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Maybe I did not express myself correctly.
I need the menu button.
Pull one time down. Only button is displayed.
the second time pull down.
Only then will the menu be displayed completely

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot for that? The above images you have added are unable to clarify that.